# Funcion no esta definina onclick

Tags: php, botón

Estoy teniendo el siguiente problema, tengo este boton:
[image: Boton]

Y esta linkeado a esta funcion:
[image: Funcion llamada por el boton]

Que llama a la funcion:
[image: ajax call]
Pero cuando toco el boton me dice que la funcion no esta definida, que puede ser?
Gracias!

Comment: Debe ser onClick en lugar de onclick?

Comment: Lo cambie a onClick y me sigue tirando el error de que no esta definido

Comment: En Javascript se considera una mala práctica poner funciones *in line*, o sea, embebidas en los elementos HTML. ¿El motivo? El contenido HTML y el código Javascript se hacen totalmente dependientes uno de otro, el mantenimiento se dificulta y ocurren errores como el actual por diversos motivos. Por poner un ejemplo, si colocas ese onclick a 5 mil archivos HTML y mañana la función debe cambiar de nombre o debe recibir más parámetros... te quiero ver buscando donde rayos pusiste esa función para modificarla (tienes que encontrar los 5 mil archivos entre 9,999 archivos) ¡! ...

Comment: ... ¿Acaso no es más simple asignar el onclick en Javascript, usando el `id` del botón? Así, la función estará declarada en un sólo archivo Javascript, no en 5 mil onclick de los HTML y si mañana hay que cambiar algo, lo cambias en un sólo sitio, no en 5 mil sitios. Por otra parte, cuando plantees preguntas en el sitio, evita poner imágenes del código, es mejor poner el texto directamente, pues es más fácil de revisar y se puede usar para reproducir el problema o para aportar respuestas. Con una imagen es imposible hacerlo. Saludos.